# Java getting the polygon height at a certain x position

Tags: java, math, polygon

I'm using libGDX.
I want to get they height of a polygon, when i know the x position.

This photo can explain better:

[image]

Comment: Which height would you want? There are 2 that are possible, your picture demonstrates this quite nicely.

Comment: Any of them, i think you say that one height is from the 0 coordinate of the ground, and one from the start of the polygon

Comment: Well, the biggest problem is deciding which you want. From there, its as easy as iterating the points in order and using line intercepts. You would have the line-vertical, denoted by `x` and the line generated by two points.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a class for coordinates:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Let's suppose you have a class containing your Polygon coordinates:

```
public class Polygon
{
    protected Coordinate[] points;

    public Polygon(Coordinate[] points)
    {
        this.points = points;
    }

    protected doulbe getMaxHeight(double x)
    {
        double height = 0;
        for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < points.length; pointIndex++)
        {
            int nextIndex = (pointIndex + 1) % points.length;
            if ((points[pointIndex] >= x) && (points[nextIndex] <= x) ||
                (points[nextIndex] >= x) && (points[pointIndex] <= x))
            {
                height = Math.max(height, Math.max(points[pointIndex].y, points[nextIndex].x));
            }
        }
        return height;
    }
}
```

The code is untested, but you can try that out and please let me know about the results.